# How can I tell EE NOT to Cache a Session Variable

Tags: sessions, mustash

Firstly, I am new to ExpressionEngine.

I am using this "session variables" plugin:
https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/session-variables-plugin

The templates are being cached (with Mustash) and it is caching the session variable when I output it to the page. Even if the sessions value is changed. I need to this to be dynamic. How can I tell EE not to cache this value? Thanks in advance.

`{exp:session_variables:get name='landingPage'}`

Comment: You can escape stash, not sure if works with mustach but def worth a shot https://github.com/croxton/Stash/wiki/%7Bexp:stash:cache%7D

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To solve this issue I just abandoned using PHP sessions entirely and manually set and retrieved the session cookie value via javascript.

**Opinion below beware!**

> I believe the ExpressionEngine templating language, and the design methodology behind EE is of bad taste. Too heavy of a reliance on abstraction through dependencies.